# Make-array in SBCL

Tags: compilation, lisp, common-lisp, vm-implementation

How does `make-array` work in SBCL? Are there some equivalents of `new` and `delete` operators in C++, or is it something else, perhaps assembler level?

I peeked into the source, but didn't understand anything.

Comment: I had a look at the code but it would be much too much work for me to go through it all. The basic idea is: there is some memory representation of arrays that looks like some fields like dimensions, fill pointer, element type, and rank. This layout is largely decided by the compiler and there is then a bunch of interaction between the implementation of the library and the compiler to decide what magic constants go in those fields to make an array.

Comment: @DanRobertson 
But how exactly does it allocate memory? Is there some lisp operator for it?

Comment: It will be built in to the implementation/compiler. Memory management is a large and different topic. In the simplest case the implementation just bumps a pointer. In a more complex case it might need to get something from a free list, split things up or even garbage collect first

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using SBCL compiled from source and an environment like Emacs/Slime, it is possible to navigate the code quite easily using <kbd>M-.</kbd> (meta-point). Basically, the `make-array` symbol is bound to multiple things: `deftransform` definitions, and a `defun`. The `deftransform` are used mostly for optimization, so better just follow the function, first.

The `make-array` function delegates to an internal `make-array%` one, which is quite complex: it checks the parameters, and dispatches to different specialized implementation of arrays, based on those parameters: a bit-vector is implemented differently than a string, for example.

If you follow the case for `simple-array`, you find a function which calls `allocate-vector-with-widetag`, which in turn calls `allocate-vector`.

Now, `allocate-vector` is bound to several objects, multiple `defoptimizers` forms, a function and a `define-vop` form.

The function is only:

```
(defun allocate-vector (type length words)
  (allocate-vector type length words))
```

Even if it looks like a recursive call, it isn't.

The `define-vop` form is a way to define how to compile a *call* to `allocate-vector`. In the function, and anywhere where there is a call to `allocate-vector`, the compiler knows how to write the assembly that implements the built-in operation. But the function itself is defined so that there is an entry point with the same name, and a function object that wraps over that code.

`define-vop` relies on a Domain Specific Language in SBCL that abstracts over assembly. If you follow the definition, you can find different vops (virtual operations) for `allocate-vector`, like `allocate-vector-on-heap` and `allocate-vector-on-stack`.

Allocation on heap translates into a call to `calc-size-in-bytes`, a call to `allocation` and `put-header`, which most likely allocates memory and tag it (I followed the definition to `src/compiler/x86-64/alloc.lisp`).
How memory is allocated (and garbage collected) is another problem.

`allocation` emits assembly code using `%alloc-tramp`, which in turns executes the following:

```
(invoke-asm-routine 'call (if to-r11 'alloc-tramp-r11 'alloc-tramp) node)
```

There are apparently assembly routines called `alloc-tramp-r11` and `alloc-tramp`, which are predefined assembly instructions. A comment says:

```
;;; Most allocation is done by inline code with sometimes help
;;; from the C alloc() function by way of the alloc-tramp
;;; assembly routine.
```

There is a base of C code for the runtime, see for example `/src/runtime/alloc.c`.

The `-tramp` suffix stands for [trampoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)).

Have also a look at `src/runtime/x86-assem.S`.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Didn't expect C code in such a place, thought it there was only a small C chunk in a place where they handle errors, or smth.

Comment: I wonder if I myself can use all these functions without much specific knowledge.